# Creating a Sequence with a particular length in R

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to create a path sequence. The following is a sample dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(
  sess_id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), 
  Page = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D")),
  .Names = c("sess_id", "Page"),
  row.names = c(NA, -12L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

This is the table:

| sess_id | Page |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | C |
| 4 | B |
| 7 | B |
| 7 | C |
| 7 | D |
| 7 | A |
| 7 | D |

I would like to add three columns like so:

| sess_id | Page | Path | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | A |  |  |  |
| 4 | B | AB | A | B |
| 4 | C | ABC | A | C |
| 4 | D | ABCD | A | D |
| 4 | A | ABCDA | A | A |
| 4 | C | BCDAC | B | C |
| 4 | B | CDACB | C | B |
| 7 | B |  |  |  |
| 7 | C | BC | B | C |
| 7 | D | BCD | B | D |
| 7 | A | BCDA | B | A |
| 7 | D | BCDAD | B | D |

I am trying to create a path sequence of five pages in each session. And map the start and end of that five-page sequence.

Comment: What is the logic for how the path is created please?

Comment: @user20650 last 5 rows within sess_id, notice the 6th row, it doesn't include 1st row anymore.

Comment: Why is the downvote, repro data, expected outcome is included, problem is clear.

Answer (score 5):

## Update

If you don't want to keep elements in `Path` as a string, you can use

```
df %>%
  group_by(sess_id) %>%
  mutate(Path = lapply(accumulate(Page, c), last, 5)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    Start = Page[pmax(1, (1:n()) - 4)],
    End = Page
  )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   sess_id Page  Path      Start End  
     <dbl> <chr> <list>    <chr> <chr>
 1       4 A     <chr [1]> A     A
 2       4 B     <chr [2]> A     B
 3       4 C     <chr [3]> A     C
 4       4 D     <chr [4]> A     D
 5       4 A     <chr [5]> A     A
 6       4 C     <chr [5]> B     C
 7       4 B     <chr [5]> C     B
 8       7 B     <chr [1]> D     B
 9       7 C     <chr [2]> A     C
10       7 D     <chr [3]> C     D
11       7 A     <chr [4]> B     A
12       7 D     <chr [5]> B     D
```

---

## Previous Solution

You can use `accumulate` + `substr` like below

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(sess_id) %>%
  mutate(Path = accumulate(Page, paste0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    Path = substr(Path, nchar(Path) - 4, nchar(Path)),
    Start = substr(Path, 1, 1),
    End = Page
  )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   sess_id Page  Path  Start End  
     <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1       4 A     A     A     A
 2       4 B     AB    A     B
 3       4 C     ABC   A     C
 4       4 D     ABCD  A     D
 5       4 A     ABCDA A     A
 6       4 C     BCDAC B     C
 7       4 B     CDACB C     B
 8       7 B     B     B     B
 9       7 C     BC    B     C
10       7 D     BCD   B     D
11       7 A     BCDA  B     A
12       7 D     BCDAD B     D
```

Comment: thanks a lot. However, this is not effective if the Page column has real names like Create, Start, About, etc. Would you have a way around that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `rollapplyr` from package `zoo` to create a rolling sequence per group of `sess_id`. Then the 1st and the last characters of the sequences are the `Start` and `End` columns, respectively.

```r
df <- structure(list(
  sess_id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), 
  Page = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D")),
  .Names = c("sess_id", "Page"),
  row.names = c(NA, -12L),
  class = "data.frame")


fun <- function(x, width) {
  y1 <- zoo::rollapplyr(x, width = seq(width), paste, collapse = "")[1:(width - 1L)]
  y2 <- zoo::rollapplyr(x, width = width, paste, collapse = "")
  c(y1, y2)
}

sp <- split(df$Page, df$sess_id)
l <- 5L

df$Path <- unlist(lapply(sp, fun, width = l))
df$Start <- substr(df$Path, 1, 1)
df$End <- substring(df$Path, nchar(df$Path))
df
#>    sess_id Page  Path Start End
#> 1        4    A     A     A   A
#> 2        4    B    AB     A   B
#> 3        4    C   ABC     A   C
#> 4        4    D  ABCD     A   D
#> 5        4    A ABCDA     A   A
#> 6        4    C BCDAC     B   C
#> 7        4    B CDACB     C   B
#> 8        7    B     B     B   B
#> 9        7    C    BC     B   C
#> 10       7    D   BCD     B   D
#> 11       7    A  BCDA     B   A
#> 12       7    D BCDAD     B   D
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The following works and uses tidyverse. `Path` is first created as all letters within each `sess_id` stuck together. Then take the first to nth letters, where n is the row number. Then take between 0 and 5 chars from the end of string.

The `Start` and `End` are just the first and last letters of `Path`.

At the end we set `Path`, `Start` and `End` to `""` when the length of `Path` is one.

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(sess_id) %>% 
  mutate(Path = paste0(Page , collapse = "") %>% 
           str_sub( 1 , row_number()) %>% 
           str_extract( "\\w{0,5}$"),
         
         Start = str_extract(Path , "^\\w"), 
         End = str_extract(Path , "\\w$")) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Path, Start, End), ~if_else(str_length(Path)==1 , "" , .)))

> df
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   sess_id [2]
   sess_id Page  Path    Start End  
     <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1       4 A     ""      ""    ""   
 2       4 B     "AB"    "A"   "B"  
 3       4 C     "ABC"   "A"   "C"  
 4       4 D     "ABCD"  "A"   "D"  
 5       4 A     "ABCDA" "A"   "A"  
 6       4 C     "BCDAC" "B"   "C"  
 7       4 B     "CDACB" "C"   "B"  
 8       7 B     ""      ""    ""   
 9       7 C     "BC"    "B"   "C"  
10       7 D     "BCD"   "B"   "D"  
11       7 A     "BCDA"  "B"   "A"  
12       7 D     "BCDAD" "B"   "D"
```